# How to enable CUDA GPU acceleration for Spacy on Windows

Tags: pytorch, gpu, spacy

As you may know SpaCy is a great library for processing texts and building your own models for extracting and processing data. One of the

When I tried using `en_core_web_trf` model for getting entities from english texts, I came to sad outcome - model was very slow when working on CPU. So, I tried to get GPU work as powerhouse for this task.

But trying to enable GPU acceleration may be challenging - drivers, CUDA, pytorch, specific spacy installation...

After few failed attempts I found correct way for enablement of GPU in SpaCy. Hope it will help

Answer (score 4):

Steps:

1. Install latest stable drivers for your GPU from nVidia website ([download](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx)).
2. Install CUDA Toolkit from nVidia website (I used [archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive)). For example, version 11.6 is stable and can be used without hesitation. Reboot.
3. Let's check correctness of installation

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Dec_17_18:28:54_Pacific_Standard_Time_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.55z
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.30794723_0
```

4. Install PyTorch from this [download link](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). PyTorch will provide us backend for GPU support.
   Check following options:

> Build: Stable
>  OS: Windows
>  Package: pip
>  Compute Platform:
> Cuda 11.6

After checking list of these options you should be able to copy following string

`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116`

Run this string in cmd with admin rights

5. Check if PyTorch is installed correctly

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

6. Install SpaCy from following [webpage](https://spacy.io/usage). Please check following options:

> OS – Windows
>  Platform – x86
>  package manager – pip
>  Hardware
> – GPU
>  CUDA - 11.6

7. Using admin rights run following code in cmd:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U “spacy[cuda116]”
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

8. Let's check that everything is working just fine:

```
spacy.require_gpu()
load_nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
doc = load_nlp(text)
```

, where `text` - any text on English you want to process

Speaking about acceleration - SpaCy has it's own [benchmarks](https://spacy.io/usage/facts-figures#benchmarks-speed)